# What could be the reason for defective print with this picture?

Tags: printing, printer

I have an Epson L6190 printer. And on several occasions on different days I had printed 20 or more pages for different customers of documents that have exactly this green logo at the top on each page. Only 1 page gets this defective print design every time this happens.

[image]

Something about this logo always messes up the print job. It looks like after or while it prints the logo, it slightly turns the page by a certain small angle (less than 5 degrees) counter clockwise which causes the crease. Can someone explain What mechanism in the printer could cause this defective print job when it comes across this logo? This is definitely not a coincidence as this never happens with any other document print with all customers I ever had.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the crease in the page?

Comment: yes that crease is the defect but only happens when the page has exactly this green logo at the top. It looks like after or while it prints the logo, it slightly turns the page by a certain small angle counter clockwise which causes the crease.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that after printing a lot of colour (green), somehow your printer's had her sticky. Try cleaning your printer. If that doesn't help, then probably the only option is to print smaller batches

Comment: try printing the page upside down and see if that has any impact

Comment: @BlindSpots hey that's an amazing idea! Can I instruct the printer to do an upside down print for a microsoft word doc?

Comment: Don't know but you could save it as a PDF (or image) and flip it it on your PC before printing.  It will give you some more data points.

Comment: Your picture doesn't look like typical inkjet paper. This may be just the picture but if that is the case perhaps it plays a role in the problem.  At first blush your problem looks like a paper feed issue.  I would do more exhaustive testing with that paper and other word documents.  Also look at the paper itself in the tray to insure it isn't contributing to the issue, like has some imperfections from humidity or something.

Comment: no it isn't the paper. it's plain paper of good quality (substance 20). i have printed thousands of pages perfectly fine. but whenever i encounter a student printing this document with that logo, it does this. so i'm quite confident it is the logo causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Purely a guess - the colour as CMYK manages to be above your printer's 'safe loading' values for ink coverage*. Doing a quick & dirty conversion to CMYK I get a coverage of 225%, which *ought* to be just about safe. I can't emulate that actual printer's conversion though.
Doing the same from the photo of the printed document gives 240%, which is getting very borderline. There is no accuracy in my method though - we don't have anything like a calibrated workflow for my figures to be accurate.

Try making the colour 10 - 15% lighter & see what happens - even more just as an experiment.

Shifting it this far brings it under 200%. As the printed document from the photo already looks significantly darker than the original image, you might be able to push this quite a way before it looks too light on paper.

[image]

If you have control over the actual CMYK ink blend you could try dropping cyan & replacing with black, which would require much less ink to give [very approximately] the same colour. If you work entirely in RGB, then you have to rely on the printer's own conversions.

*'Safe' can depend on many things, from the type & consistency of the ink, to the weight & absorbency of the paper, how close the heads pass, etc. It's a broad spectrum safety margin. 'Too much' ink & something can just catch where it shouldn't, causing the paper to be dragged out of alignment. It could also damage your heads, so it's something you need to find a long-term fix for.

Comment: Okay, I definitely need to read up on this.